# можно ли получить все координаты маршрута, не добавляя его на карту?

Tags: javascript, карты, leafletjs, картография

Когда я добавляю `routingControl` на карту (я использую карту от `leaflet` и `leaflet-routing-machine`), у меня есть все координаты маршрута в этом объекте:

```
const routingControl = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: route.points,
}).addTo(map)

console.log("routingControl", routingControl)
```

В `routingControl._line._route.coordinates` у меня есть все рассчитанные координаты

Могу ли я получить эти координаты без `.addTo(map)`?

Comment: Чьи карты то? Так не ясно

Comment: @eri, это карта leaflet, я не смог добавить теги

Comment: В тексте можно указать было

Comment: @eri, поправил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Координаты получить без вызова `.addTo(map)` можно плагином запроса, который использует `leaflet-routing-machine` `L.Routing.OSRMv1`. [Документация](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-osrmv1).

Пример:

```js
const osrmv1 = L.Routing.osrmv1();
osrmv1.route([{
    latLng: L.latLng(57.74, 11.94)
  }, {
    latLng: L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
  }],
  (err, route) => console.log(route[0].coordinates));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
```

Также комментарий к вашему вопрос: `routingControl._line._route.coordinates` - плохая идея использовать такой доступ к координатам. Обращение происходит к внутренним переменным, данные которых не гарантируются контрактами. Для получения координат из плагина `L.Routing.control` нужно использовать `.on('routesfound', callback)`. [Документация](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#routingresultevent).

Comment: Супер, спасибо)